# Python: How to extract alternate column to array from a 2D array?

Tags: python, arrays, file

I'm new to python for optimization problem. I have got a data set in a txt file, and would like to extract the data into two different arrays.
The 2 arrays are from the alternate columns of the data set.

Text File: test_data.txt

```
1 2 3 4 5 6
2 3 4 5 6 7
3 4 5 6 7 8
```

Expected result:

```
array1 = [[1,3,5],[2,4,6],[3,5,7]]
array2 = [[2,4,6],[3,5,7],[4,6,8]]
```

Below code is what I have done, I'm able to extract the whole table, but unable to extract the alternate columns due to type error.

```
with open("test_data.txt","r") as test_table:
    array=[]    
    for line in test_table:
       array.append([int(x) for x in line.split()])

array1=array[:,0::2]
array2=array[:,1::2]
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The type error you're encountering is because `array` is a regular array/list, not a NumPy array. As a result, you can't use NumPy-like indexing syntax with a regular array. To resolve this issue, you have a couple of options:

**Option 1: Convert the array to a NumPy array**

If you prefer to work with a NumPy array, you can convert array to a NumPy array using the np.array() function. Here's an example:

```py
import numpy as np

with open("test_data.txt","r") as test_table:
    array=[]    
    for line in test_table:
       array.append([int(x) for x in line.split()])
    
array = np.array(array)

array1=array[:,0::2]
array2=array[:,1::2]
```

Now, you can use the NumPy indexing syntax `array[:, 0::2]` and `array[:, 1::2]` to access the desired elements.

**Option 2: Work with a regular array**

If you prefer to continue using a regular array, you can achieve a similar result using list comprehensions. Here's an example:

```py
with open("test_data.txt","r") as test_table:
    array=[]    
    for line in test_table:
       array.append([int(x) for x in line.split()])

array1 = [row[0::2] for row in array]
array2 = [row[1::2] for row in array]
```

In this case, `array1` will contain the elements at even indices from each sublist of array, and `array2` will contain the elements at odd indices from each sublist.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to maintain your syntax, you have to use `numpy`, since that is not valid syntax for python list. This code will work as you want:

```
import numpy as np
with open("test_data.txt", "r") as test_table:
    array = []
    for line in test_table:
        array.append([int(x) for x in line.split()])
array = np.array(array)
array1 = array[:, 0::2]
array2 = array[:, 1::2]
```

Otherwise, if you don't want to use `numpy`, you can leverage list comprehensions:

```
with open("test_data.txt", "r") as test_table:
    array = []
    for line in test_table:
        array.append([int(x) for x in line.split()])


array1 = [[row[i] for i in range(len(row)) if i % 2 == 0] for row in array]
array2 = [[row[i] for i in range(len(row)) if i % 2 != 0] for row in array]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use numpy it is easy

```
import numpy as np
array =[[1,2,3,4,5,6],
[2,3,4,5,6,7],
[3,4,5,6,7,8]]

arr = np.asarray(array)
print(arr[:][:,0::2])
print(arr[:][:,1::2])
```

Without numpy

```
arr2 = [i[0::2] for i in array]
print(arr2)
```